# scheduling order (timeline) for FCFS, SJN, SRT, Round Robin

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduler, round-robin

I got this question from my friend, new to the operating system area.

We got:

Job number 1
Arrival Time = 0, CPU cycles = 80,

Job number 2
Arrival Time = 22, CPU cycles = 60,

Job number 3
Arrival Time = 44, CPU cycles = 24,

Job Number 4
Arrival Time = 55, CPU cycles = 40.

How can I do the scheduling order for FCFS, SJN, SRT, Round Robin (using a time quantum of 20).

Thank you. If you can give me any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

**FCFS: stands for first come first serve** Means the job that comes first must be executed at first so it will do it it's work in this way.

Job number 1 then Job number 2  then Job number 3  then Job Number 4.

It will not stop executing when the new process comes in. It has disadvantage that a short process has to wait for a longer process to finish because suppose a shorter process comes at end then it has to wait for all long processes on queue to end.

**Shortest job first**
This can't be implemented for short-term-scheduler.I will explain why at the end

You next algorithm is **SRT** is based on this algorithm. Here we get jobs in an order and we don't swith the cpu if the new job is short. However they arrival time of the processes is different so it will first execute job1 then job2 then job3 then job4. May be you think that job3is shorter and it should switch cpu but that only happends if you are allowed to preempt the process and if that's the case then it's not **SJB** but **SRT**.

However if you have two process at time 0 with length/burst = 80 and 40 then it will pick the process whose burst is 40.

**Only for long term scheduler** This algorithm is not for short-term scheduler because you need to know the length/burst of next process which takes time or you can also try to approximate time , there is a complex formula but that does not work always.

**SRT: stands for shortest remaining time first:** A **premptive** algorithm/version of shortest job first.

- First job : arrival time 0 and CPU cycle 80
- second job: arrival time 22 and CPU cycle 60
- 3rd job : arrival time 44 and CPU cycle 24
- 4rth job: arrival time 55 and CPU cycle 40

At time 0 the only process you have is F1(means first job) after 22 m-seconds a new process is placed in queue so the scheduler computes it's length and first job was executed for  22 m-seconds now it's remaining time is 80-22 = 58 and the length of new process is 60 which is greater than 58 so scheduler does not switch to the new process. After 44 m-seconds a third job comes in so you have 80-44 = 36 and time required by 3rd job is only 24 so the scheduler places all results of that process on stack and allocatess CPU to the third job/process.

After 55 second another process is placed on the queue with length 40 but the third process is still shorted so the first job is process 3 which will be finished for the first.

- Job 1 runs for 44 seconds :     remaining time = 36 at this point Job **3** gets processor.
- job 3 runs for 24 seconds: finished.

  At this point we have job 1 with 36 m-seconds , job 2 with 60 m-seconds and job 4 with 40 seconds. So scheduler allocates again CPU to job 1 because it's the shortest and once it's finished then it allocates to job 4 and then job 2.

Disadvantage: Too much preemption require also time.

**Round-Robin:** Similar to **First-come-first-serve** the only difference is that it allocates equal time to each process(means allows preemption where fcfs does not allow). Here you use time quantum of few m-seconds.

There are two possibilities: Either the process completes it's burst then the process releases the CPU voluntarily if not the after the time quantum is over the scheduler take the CPU away from this process and allocates it to the next.

If you have N process in queue then every process will get 1/n cpu time in chunks of at most q time units.

- Job1 gets CPU for 20 m-seconds and because there is no other process in queue then this job1 gets again cpu for next 20 sm-seconds.
- As the first job has executed 2*20 this time there has been a new process(job2) in the queue so this process will get CPU for 20 seconds. When the job2 was executing there are two other process placed in the queue.(job3 and job4). 
  Now job3 gets the CPU for 20 seconds and then job4 gets CPU for 20 m-seconds.
  After first cycle:
- Job1 has executed 2*20 ; remaining time = 40
- job2 has executed 20 ; remaining time =  40
- job3 has executed 20; remaining time = 4
- job4 has executed 20; remaining time = 20.

After second cycle:
 - Job1 has executed 40-20 ; remaining time = 20

- job2 has executed 40-20 ; remaining time =  20
- job3 has executed 4-4; remaining time = finished/only executed for 4 seconds.
- job4 has executed 20-20; remaining time = 0/finished.

After third cycle:
 - Job1 has executed 20 - 20 ; remaining time = 0

- job2 has executed 20 -20 ; remaining time =  0

The performance of this algorithm depends on the size of time-quantum. If you have small time quantum then too many preemptions/context-switches (moving processes to stack and allocating cpu to new process) is also not good and if time quantum is too large then it's also not good and try to think why? :D

Comment: Thank you for answering my question first. I am new to the IT subject, can you recommand me some way that i can get familiar with these things ? the scheduling algorithm ? because i am really confused about them now

Comment: Read book, Operating System concepts by Abraham Silberschatz